# Sorting elements by price, the order is 10, 100, 12, 13, 140?

Tags: javascript

I have a little js switch method for sorting some div elements by title (a-z) and price (low-high) but it does sort properly, e.g. 10 is followed by 100, then by 11 ?

here's the code

```
sortPrice: function() {

    switch ($('select[name=sortOrder]').val()) {

        case('priceAsc'):

            $('.adventureRow').sortElements(function(a, b) {
                return $(a).attr('id') > $(b).attr('id') ? 1 : -1;
            });

            break;

        case('priceDesc'):

            $('.adventureRow').sortElements(function(a, b) {
                return $(a).attr('id') < $(b).attr('id') ? 1 : -1;
            });

            break;

        case('alphaAsc'):

            $('.adventureRow').sortElements(function(a,b) {
                return $(a).attr('title') > $(b).attr('title') ? 1 : -1;
            });

            break;

        case('alphaDesc'):

            $('.adventureRow').sortElements(function(a,b) {
                return $(a).attr('title') < $(b).attr('title') ? 1 : -1;
            });

            break;

        case('default'):

            $('.adventureRow').sortElements(function(a,b) {
                return $(a).attr('style') > $(b).attr('style') ? 1 : -1;
            });


    }
```

I think I'm missing something to do with declaring the values as numeric, but I'm not sure of what .

Comment: Because you are using string comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are doing string comparison for numerical values....

```
 return +$(a).attr('id') < +$(b).attr('id') ? 1 : -1;
```

So the string `2` is greater than `100` because the string comparison is from left to right and when it matches `2` and `1`, `2` is greater... it doesn't compare the numerical value

Comment: would wrapping the string in parseInt() work?  like parseInt($(a).attr('id'))

Comment: Yes... `+` is a shortcut to do it